# Prove the Fibonacci relation $F_{2k} = (F_{2(k-1)}^2 + 1)/F_{2(k-2)}$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, fibonacci-numbers

Let $F_k$ be the Fibonacci sequence defined by $F_0=F_1=1$ and $F_k=F_{k-1} + F_{k-2}$

I am trying to show the relation $F_{2k}=(F_{2(k-1)}^2 + 1)/F_{2(k-2)}$ for $k=2,3,4,...$

I first attempted to prove this by induction however I cannot seem to see any simplification. I then used Cassini's identity $F_{n}^2 - F_{n+1}F_{n-1}=(-1)^{n-1}$ to obtain

$(F_{2(k-1)}^2 + 1)/F_{2(k-2)} = (F_{2(k-1)+1}F_{2(k-1)-1} + (-1)^{2(k-1)-1}+1)/F_{2(k-2)}$

$=(F_{2k-1}F_{2k-3}+2)/F_{2k-4}$

However I am similarly stuck with this. Can anyone help with finding a relation which will help me to prove the induction or point me in the right direction.

Comment: Hint: Find a three-term recursion for $F_0,F_2,F_4,\ldots$ first (i.e., find constants $a$ and $b$ such that $F_{2m} = aF_{2\left(m-1\right)} + bF_{2\left(m-2\right)}$ for all $m$).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your definition of the Fibonacci numbers is not consistent with the customary definition, which is $$\begin{align*} F_0 &= 0, \\ F_1 &= 1, \\ F_n &= F_{n-1} + F_{n-2}. \end{align*}$$  You instead have $F_0 = 1$, which shifts your sequence by $1$.  This is the reason for the discrepancy.

We will use the customary definition, in which case the identity to be proven is $$F_{2n+1} = \frac{F_{2n-1}^2 + 1}{F_{2n-3}},$$ which is obtained by substituting $2k = 2n+1$, and is equivalent to the identity $$1 = F_{2n+1} F_{2n-3} - F_{2n-1}^2.$$
A proof by induction is straightforward.  Also possible is an approach via the identity $$F_n = \frac{1}{\sqrt{5}} \left( \varphi^n - \bar \varphi^n \right),$$ where $\varphi = (1 + \sqrt{5})/2$ and $\bar \varphi = (1 - \sqrt{5})/2$.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. Changing the Fibonacci definition helped, and instead of using an inductive method of proof I showed the relation directly using Catalan's identity.